# How to write a sum and count for example below?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

The below SQL query sums up each penalty mark per question in a session:

```
SELECT s.SessionId,q.QuestionId,SUM(pm.PenaltyMarks)
    FROM Session s
    INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
    INNER JOIN Penalty_Marks pm ON q.QuestionId = pm.QuestionId
    WHERE (s.SessionId = 30)
    GROUP BY s.SessionId,q.QuestionId
```

Below is what the output displays:

```
SessionId  QuestionId  Sum(pm.PenaltyMarks)
30         77          4
30         38          3
30         39          4
```

But what I want to happen is now sum up all of the penalty marks within the Session. So in the above example it will add up the penalty marks together for session 30 to output the total penalty marks as `11`. But my question is how can this be achieved?

So below is what it should look like:

```
SessionId  TotalPenaltyMarks
30         11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `q.QuestionId`

```
SELECT  s.SessionId, 
        SUM(pm.PenaltyMarks) TotalPenaltyMarks
FROM    Session s
        INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
        INNER JOIN Penalty_Marks pm ON q.QuestionId = pm.QuestionId
WHERE   s.SessionId = 30
GROUP   BY s.SessionId
```

The `GROUP BY` clause is already optional since you are already filtering for a specific `SessionId`.

Comment: But only because MySQL is peculiarly forgiving!

Comment: Thank you very much :) I have been trying for ages trying to do a SUM and COUNT method but yeah, I wasted my time haha :)